# Droplet Contact or indirect physical contact

Tags: disease-transmission, sneeze-sneezing

I am trying to figure out what kind of transmission ..." non-vectored infectious disease through sneezing on someone " would be.

I want to say droplet because its directly on that person, but not sure
what the difference between droplet contact and indirect physical contact is?

Comment: Sneezing would be droplet. Indirect physical contact refers to contact with an object by both parties (a doorknob, for example).